# Finding combinations of specific values

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I don't know how to write the query for below.

My table is

```
col1 col2 
5   1
5   5
5   6
5   7
4   5
4   8
4   9
4   3
3   3
3   5
```

I need to select distinct col1 id where both parameters exists in col2.
eg. if i send 6,7 it should send me 5

Comment: please note this is not a recursive query. change the title accordingly.

Comment: Thanks please suggest a title , will do needful

Comment: Your question should provide the actual table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement) and your Postgres version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT col1
FROM mytable
WHERE col2 IN (6, 7)
GROUP BY col1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT col2) = 2
```

Comment: (I hope the DISTINCT is redundant.)

Comment: No unique constraints are known, so the DISTINCT is needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably among the fastest solutions:

```
SELECT col1  -- already DISTINCT?
FROM   tbl t1
JOIN   tbl t2 USING (col1)
WHERE  t1.col2 = 6
AND    t2.col2 = 7;
```

Assuming a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` constraint on `(col1, col2)`, like it's typically implemented. Else add `DISTINCT`.

There are many other ways to implement relational division. Here are some:

- [How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation/7774879#7774879)